# Email sending issue in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7, email

I have a setup site through WordPress on Godaddy. Domain on another Godaddy account which linked to this hosting Godaddy account.

The site has a contact form which setup using [Contact Form 7](https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/) plugin for WordPress.

Now, while filling up form and send then got below error.

> could not instantiate mail function

Email sending functionality is working on hosting server which I tested but in this form of WordPress no working.

I tried but not found any issue. Anyone have an idea or suggestion.

Thanks

Comment: First test, Does an email get send if you create a new user? (that email is handled by WordPress not cCF7)

Comment: use "wp email smtp" plugin, then it will work

Comment: You need to setup WP SMTP. Find a great article here https://nerodev.com/how-to-setup-wp-smtp-to-receive-emails/